# How do you get % of records per specific count grouping

Tags: mysql, group-by, percentage

I have the following data in a table called `users`

```
   userId   | orgId 
    1       | 1           
    2       | 1            
    3       | 2        
    4       | 2       
    5       | 2
```

I have the following data in a table called `activities`

```
userId   | activityId | type
1        | 11         | a    
1        | 12         | a     
1        | 13         | a
1        | 14         | b
1        | 15         | b
1        | 16         | c     
1        | 17         | c
1        | 18         | c
2        | 19         | a
2        | 20         | a
2        | 21         | c
2        | 22         | c
```

I need to be able to calculate the % of users within each `orgId` who:

1. have only 1 record in the `activities' table where`type` = 'c'
2. have 5 records in the `activities` table where `type` = 'c'
3. have 10 records in the `activities` table where `type` = 'c'
4. have 50% of their records in the `activities` table where `type` = 'c'
5. have 80% of their records in the `activities` table where `type` = 'c'

So the result should be in this (hopefully possible) format:

```
orgId|% who have 1| % who have 5| % who have 10| % who have 50%| % who have 80% 
1    | 20         | 54          | 12           | 23            | 32
2    | 22         | 44          | 32           | 44            | 2
3    | 28         | 34          | 24           | 11            | 43
4    | 10         | 14          | 27           | 25            | 45
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: "have 5 records" - exactly 5 or at least 5? Same question for points 3 to 5

Comment: Thank you for the question. You are right, should have been more clear. Meant at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "conditional aggregation" to get the count and percentage per user:

```
select userId,
  sum(type = 'c') as countC,
  sum(type = 'c') * 100 / count(*) as percentC
from activities
group by userId
```

The result for your sample data would be:

```
| userId | countC | percentC |
|--------|--------|----------|
|      1 |      3 |     37.5 |
|      2 |      2 |       50 |
```

This can be used as a subquery joined with the `users` table. Then you can again use "conditional aggregation" to get the expected result:

```
select u.orgId,
  sum(countC = 1) as `only 1`,
  sum(countC >= 5) as `at least 5`,
  sum(countC >= 10) as `at least 10`,
  sum(percentC >= 50) as `at least 50%`,
  sum(percentC >= 80) as `at least 80%`
from (
  select userId,
    sum(type = 'c') as countC,
    sum(type = 'c') * 100 / count(*) as percentC
  from activities
  group by userId
) a
join users u using(userId)
group by u.orgId
```

Your sample data is not the best for that query. However you would get:

```
| orgId | only 1 | at least 5 | at least 10 | at least 50% | at least 80% |
|-------|--------|------------|-------------|--------------|--------------|
|     1 |      0 |          0 |           0 |            1 |            0 |
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b30dae/2

Comment: I will test this today and comment back. So thankful for your response